# How can I communicate between a server and a client using AWS when they are on different networks?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to establish a basic connection with my server from the client program. When I run my client/server on the same network, it works fine, but I don't know where to start when my client program is on my PC but  my server program is on the EC2 instance.

I have set up an EC2 linux instance on AWS, and have loaded the server code onto it. The Client is on my PC.

To run the server, I'm using:
`java GreetingServer 6000`

To run the client, I'm using:
`java GreetingClient <EC2 Public IP> 6000`

I'm new to AWS and server-client communication, so if you know any good tutorials for this, that would be great!

Server Code:

```
// File Name GreetingServer.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread {
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
   }

   public void run() {
      while(true) {
         try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + 
               serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());

            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress()
               + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();

         } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      try {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Client Code:

```
// File Name GreetingClient.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient {

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      String serverName = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      try {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

         System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You may need to make sure that the security group of your EC2 instance is allowing incoming connections on port 6000. (This can be found in the AWS UI).

Comment: The error I'm getting is:Connection timed out . I used the default security group so that allows all ports if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I think the default SG only allows incoming connections from servers with the same SG. You may need to open the port specifically for your client IP (or less securely, for all users). Check the "source" field in the SG settings.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Added the new port and it's working!